# Is shift operation running in separated instruction in thumb ISA?

Tags: arm

ARM instructions may utilize barrel shifter in its second source operand (see below assembly listed), which is part of the data process instruction so save one instruction to do shifting. I am wondering could thumb instruction utilize barrel shift in DP instructions? Or should it separate the shift operation into an independent instruction? I am asking this since thumb may not has sufficient space in the instruction to code barrel shifter.

```
mov r0, r1, LSL #1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That example's not great, since it's an alternate form of the canonical `lsl r0, r1, #1`, which *does* have a 16-bit Thumb encoding (albeit with flag-setting restrictions).

An alternative ARM instruction such as `add r0, r0, r1, lsl #1` would indeed have to be done as two Thumb instructions because as you say there just isn't room to squeeze both operations into 16 bits (hence also why you're limited to r0-r7 so registers can be encoded in 3 bits rather than 4).

Thumb-2, on the other hand, generally does have 32-bit encodings for immediate shifts of operands, so on ARMv6T2 and later architectures you can encode `add r0, r0, r1, lsl #1` as a single instruction.

The register-shifted register form, however, (e.g. `add r0, r0, r1, lsl r2`) isn't available even in Thumb-2 - you'd have to do that in 2 Thumb instructions like so:

```
lsl r1, r2
add r0, r1
```

Note that unlike the ARM instruction this sequence changes the value in r1 - if you wanted to preserve that as well you'd need an intermediate register and an extra `mov` instruction (or a Thumb-2 3-register `lsl`) - failing that the last resort would be to `bx` to ARM code.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. For your last register-shifted register form which is unavailable in thumb-2, does the assembler support split this writing (single instruction) into to 2 instructions because both ARM and thumb-2 share the same UAL syntax?

Comment: @Thomson The assembler won't do it for you automatically, but you can do the equivalent manually - I've added an example.